# In Perl regex "find & replace", how to individually pick out each match result?

Tags: regex, perl, replace, find, match

I want to use Perl to perform "search and replace" on text file, and store each match result (as an element) into an array while the replacement is done. I tried this:

```
my $txt = "
this is a statement //this is comment
//this is a line of comment
more statements //more comments
";

## foreach or while
while ($txt =~ s/(\/\/.*?\n)/foo/gs) {
        if(defined $1) {
                push (@comments, $1);
                }
        }

foreach (0..$#comments) {
        print "\@comments[$_]= @comments[$_]";
        }
```

====> However the result only gives me:

```
@comments[0]= //more comments
```

Whereas, what I expect is:

```
@comments[0]= //this is comment
@comments[1]= //this is a line of comment
@comments[2]= //more comments
```

Any hints on the issue? Thanks & 3q in advance~

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can execute code inside a replacement with the e modifier ([see perlretut](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlretut.html#Search-and-replace)):

```
my $txt = "
this is a statement //this is comment
//this is a line of comment
more statements //more comments
";

my @comments;

$txt =~ s{(//.*\n)} {push(@comments, $1);"foo"}eg;

print $_ foreach (@comments);
```

Other way: Since you are looking for inline comments, you can also work line by line with a loop and without the g modifier.

Notes:

- If you want to preserve newlines, remove `\n` from the pattern.
- removing comments from a code can be more complicated than you think. For example, the character sequence `//` can be enclosed in a string, so the more secure way to do it is to use an appropriate parser.